# In JUnit 5, why are postMethod throwing TransactionSystemException instead return ResponseEntity with bad request?

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit

I'm pretty new to Spring Boot and JUnit, so im trying to build a Rest API with validation contraints like below:

Entity class:

```
@Entity
public class CareerLevel {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer careerLevelId;

    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    @Size(max = 50)
    private String careerLevel;

    // Getters and Setters
}
```

Controller:

```
@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity<CareerLevel> postCareerLevel(@RequestBody @Valid CareerLevel careerLevel) {

    // saving data
    CareerLevel body = careerLevelRepository.save(careerLevel);
    return ResponseEntity.status(201).body(body);
}
```

When I test post method on Insomnia (or any other HTTP client) with invalid values (null, too long strings, etc) It's returning Bad Request (exactly how I expected). But when I run my Test class, It's throwing an exception called **TransactionSystemException**

Test Method:

```
@Test
void testPostCareerLevelInvalidValues() {
    CareerLevel careerLevel = new CareerLevel();
    careerLevel.setCareerLevel("tooLongStriiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiing");

    ResponseEntity<CareerLevel> response1 = controller.postCareerLevel(careerLevel); // throwing TransactionSystemException 
    assertEquals(400, response1.getStatusCode().value());
}
```

How can I handle that exception and get response data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi I tried your code locally and added a lombok annotation to create a builder for entity.

[see](https://projectlombok.org/features/Builder) `@Builder`

I recommend using `MockMvc` when testing your Controller class.

I also used mockito to mock `CareerLevelRepository` and injected it into `CareerLevelController`

```java
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class CareerLevelControllerTest {
    @Mock
    private CareerLevelRepository careerLevelRepository;
    @InjectMocks
    private CareerLevelController careerLevelController;
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(careerLevelController)
                .build();
    }
    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @Test
    void testPostCareerLevelInvalidValues() throws Exception {
        CareerLevel request = CareerLevel.builder()
                .careerLevel("tooLongStriiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiing")
                .build();

        this.mockMvc
                .perform(post("/career-levels").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(request)))
                .andExpect(status().is(400));
    }
}
```

It simply uses MockMvc to create a request rather than calling the method. `ObjectMapper` converts our created `request` to Json which has been sent as body.

Comment: Also I would like to add a tip. If your return a body, you should be returning 200 rather than 201. Because 201 is used when you only return an id or url.

Answer (score 1):

The reason your test works from HTTP client is because `@Valid` annotation  validating all of your incoming requests & hence you are getting proper response i.e. if you use longer string than 50 for `careerLevel` then too long strings, if passing `null` then null value etc.

Same is not working in your junit because you are creating plain object of `careerLevel` & setting value. This will eventually gets passed to `careerLevelRepository.save`.

Your `repository` is trying to save this object into DB & throwing [TransactionSystemException](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/TransactionSystemException.html) because of invalid input & mostly because commit got failed.